# 2019 IMC Day 1 Problem 3

Tags: inequality, contest-math

**Source:** https://www.imc-math.org.uk/?year=2019&section=problems&item=prob3q

> Let $f: (-1,1)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a twice differentiable function such that $2f'(x)+xf''(x)\geq 1$ for $x\in (-1,1)$. Prove that $\int\limits_{-1}^1 xf(x)dx\geq \frac{1}{3}$.

**My work:** We have by chain-rule

$$\frac{d}{dx}x^2f'(x)=2xf'(x)+x^2f''(x).$$

Then WLOG $x\geq 0$, and we have

$$\begin{aligned}\frac{d}{dx}x^2f'(x)\geq x\Rightarrow x^2f'(x)\geq \frac{x^2}{2}\iff f'(x)\geq \frac{1}{2}\iff f(x)-f(0)\geq \frac{x}{2}\end{aligned}.$$

And so

$$\int\limits_{-1}^1 xf(x)dx=\int\limits_{-1}^1x\left(f(x)-f(0)\right)dx\geq \int\limits_{-1}^1 \frac{x^2}{2}dx=\frac{1}{3}.$$

**Question**: I was wondering if the work makes sense or if some bits of the inequalities/work need more/less explanation.

Comment: I think x is missing two times in the first equation after "my work".

Comment: $f'(x) \geq 1/2 \iff f(x) \geq x/2$??

Comment: I agree with the comments. Also, you should show how is it "WLOG". Also, the original solution is neat and clear.

Comment: Does that not just follow from the FTC?

Comment: @Marco If $f(x) = \frac{1}{2} x - 100$ then $f'(x) \ge 1/2$ but $f(x) \not\ge x/2$.

Comment: Oh, but $f(x)-f(0)\geq \frac{x}{2}$ holds

Comment: You need to justify the step when $x \in (-1, 0)$, how you can multiply with $x$ without reversing the condition/inequality to get $(x^2f')' \ge x$.

Answer (score 5):

Just another way, let $g(x) = x f(x)$.  Then, we have
$$g'(x) = f(x) + xf'(x), \qquad g''(x) = 2f'(x) + xf''(x) \geqslant 1$$

$$\implies g'(x)-g'(0)=\int_0^x g''(t)\,dt \geqslant \int_0^x 1\, dt = x$$

$$\implies g(x) \geqslant \int_0^x (t+g'(0)) \, dt = \frac{x^2}2+g'(0)x$$

$$\implies \int_{-1}^1 g(x)\, dx \geqslant \int_{-1}^1\left(\frac{x^2}2+g'(0)x \right)\, dx = \frac13$$